# python: set a class variable programmatically before other class variables get set?

Tags: python

i have a case where i create a class inside an outer function and then return that class. the class has a specified parent class. i would like that class variable to be accessible by class methods on the parent class, these methods are called at class initialization time. in summary, i need to be able to set a class variable (not hardcoded) so that it is available before initializing other, hardcoded class variables.

here's some sample code to make that clearer:

```
class Parent(object):
    class_var = None

    @classmethod
    def get_class_var_times_two(cls):
        return cls.class_var * 2


def outer_function(class_var_value):

    class Child(Parent):
        other_var = Parent.get_class_var_times_two() # <-- at this point, somehow Child's class_var is set to class_var_value
```

Not sure if this is even possible in python. Maybe class_var_value doesn't need to be passed through the outer function. I tried using metaclasses and forcing the variable through in the class attribute dictinoary, but couldn't figure out how to set class_var on Child early enough so that it was set prior to initializing other_var. If that was possible, then this would all work. Any thoughts are appreciated!

Edit: also considered making other_var a lazy property, but that isn't an option for my use case.

Comment: is this a class that gets instansiated at some point or is it just a bunch of class level vars and funcs?

Comment: is this an actual case? is it always just *2 ? could you just do `other_var=class_var_value*2`?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `Parent.get_class_var_times_two()` calls the function with `cls = Parent`, and so consequently the value of `Parent.class_var` will be used (regardless of what context you call the function from).

So, what you want to do is call `Child.get_class_var_times_two()`. Trouble is, `Child` doesn't get defined until the `class` block finishes. You therefore need to do something like this (assuming you don't use a metaclass):

```
def outer_function(class_var_value):
    class Child(Parent):
        class_var = class_var_value
    Child.other_var = Child.get_class_var_times_two()
```

Comment: can you just set a variable like that? wouldnt you need to declare other_var to none or something in the child class?

Comment: By default, any pure-Python object (including class objects) can have attributes added at any time; this is part of the dynamic nature of Python. Note that some objects, such as primitive types, extension types or objects with `__slots__` may restrict this ability.

Comment: man I swear Ive gotten errors doing that before ...but your right it works fine (I guess I coulda just tested myself earlier ... but I was bein lazy